# Ember.js issues with model associations and fetching data

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

Preface: **I am an EmberJS newb**

I am working on a project that displays a form for a user to edit an Event. There are multiple associations in this model, one of them is `eventImages`.

`eventImages: DS.hasMany("event-image", { async: true })`

Here is my `EventImage` model

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

EventImage = DS.Model.extend
  event: DS.belongsTo('event', { async: true })

  ### NATURAL ATTRIBUTES ###
  imageUrl: DS.attr("string")
  fileName: DS.attr("string")
  fileSize: DS.attr("string")
  primary: DS.attr("boolean")
  featured: DS.attr("boolean")


`export default EventImage`
```

On the Event form, I have a place where a user can upload multiple images to be shown on the front-end for the event they are editing/creating. The problem is that I can't seem to put the pieces together on how the event model fetches the associated data from the API.

The backend (Rails) routes, are `/api/events` and `/api/events/:event_id/event_images`, but when the edit form loads, I don't see an ajax call to fetch the event images.

Here is my `edit.coffee` file in `routes`:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import DirtyConfirmRouteMixin from 'my-app/mixins/dirty-confirm-route'`

EventEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend DirtyConfirmRouteMixin,
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super(controller, model)
    @controllerFor("event-type-selector").set("promise", @store.find("event-type", forSelector: true))
    @controllerFor("venue-selector").set("promise", @store.find("venue", forSelector: true))

`export default EventEditRoute`
```

Any help at all on how to fetch associated data and displaying those items in a handlebars template would be greatly appreciated. I am certainly willing to paste any more of the code that is needed. Thanks

Edit Form Template (`templates/event/partials/form`):

```
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label label__text">More images</label>

    {{#core-image-multiple-uploader model=model processedFiles=model.eventImages}}
      Select additional event photos (10 max).
    {{/core-image-multiple-uploader}}
  </div>
```

Core Image Multiple Uploader Templte:

```
<div class="input">

  {{#each file in processedFiles}}
    <div {{action 'removeImage' _view.contentIndex}} class="preview-wrapper">
      {{event-image-preview file}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}

  <div class="input__wrapper input__wrapper--secondary">
    <div class="file-input">
      <p class="file-input__text">
        {{yield}}
      </p>
      <div class="file-input__actions">
        <input type="file" accept='image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image/tiff' class="file-upload-field" multiple />
        <a href="javascript:void({});" class="button button--medium">Choose Files</a>
        <span class="file-input__actions__filename">
          {{fileName}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Multiple Image Uploader Component

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

CoreImageMultipleUploaderComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  classNames: ["uploader--core-image"]
  processedFiles: []
  maxFiles: 10
  model: undefined

  _readFile: (idx, file) ->
    new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
      reader = new FileReader
      reader.onloadend = (evt) ->
        if evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE
          resolve
            fileName: file.name
            b64: evt.target.result
            id: idx

      reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  setImagesOnModel: (data) ->
    model = @get('model')
    currentImages = data.map((x) -> x.b64)
    model.set('images', currentImages) if model?

  _initFileChange: (->
    @$('input[type=file]').on 'change', (evnt) =>
      files = evnt.target.files
      promises = []
      if files.length and files.length <= @get('maxFiles')
        Ember.run =>
          for k,v of files
            if typeof v is 'object'
              promises.push(@_readFile(k, v))

          Promise.all(promises).then((data) =>
            @set('processedFiles', data)
            @_setImagesOnModel(data)
          )
  ).on("didInsertElement")

  actions:
    removeImage: (idx) ->
      current = @get('processedFiles')
      filtered = current.filter (x, i) -> i isnt idx
      @set('processedFiles', filtered)


`export default CoreImageMultipleUploaderComponent`
```

Comment: Why not just do `{{#each model.eventImages as |image|}}` ? Show your template.

Comment: @Lux I added in the template code

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does work. So your server response is wrong. Probably sending an empty relationship? User the ember inspector to debug.

Comment: Let me check that. Should I be seeing an XHR request to `/api/events/:event_id/event_images` in my broswer console?

Comment: Depending on the response when you fetch the event! What adapter / serializer are you using?

Comment: Oh, wait, so the backend needs to return an `event_images` array then? I am using the `ActiveModelAdapter`

Comment: I think you have to return something. Depends on your serializer tho. I don't know AMS but in JSONAPI internally you need to specify the relationship with a link, or it will be assumed that the relationship is empty, and so contains no records.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I finally got the backend to return a list of `image_ids` which is what the Ember side is looking for, but now when the call is made to retrieve each image, the route is `/api/event_images/:image_id` vs `/api/events/:event_id/event_images/:image_id`

Comment: Posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381102/emberjs-hasmany-association-fetch-not-working-properly